# Drupal 9 fatal error attempting to generate content with devel

Tags: drupal, composer-php, drupal-modules, php-7.4, drupal-9

I freshly installed Drupal 9.4.8 a few days ago. I was following the instructions on how to generate temporary content for testing from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_DEbmgqPzts&list=PLtaXuX0nEZk9MKY_ClWcPkGtOEGyLTyCO&index=33) and received a fatal error. I need to know how to fix the error so I can generate some temporary content.

The steps to reproduce

**1 Install devel module**

Use composer to install the module. According to the [docs](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) this should work with Drupal 9.

```
composer require 'drupal/devel:^5.0'
```

In the drupal admin/modules control panel, install **Devel** and **Devel Generate**.

**2 Go to drupal admin/config to generate content**

visit admin/config and click **Generate Content** option. Select your desired content types -- in my case, custom *Events* and *User Groups* content types. I specified these settings:

- generate 50 nodes
- go back 1 year
- 2 words per title

All other settings are default.

Click **Generate**.

**THIS PRODUCES THE PROBLEM**

In my browser, all I see is this:

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

I looked in the apache log and see this error message:

> [Tue Nov 01 15:11:22.216372 2022] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 344518:tid 140018374911744] [client 127.0.0.1:39852] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: Error: Class 'Drush\Utils\StringUtils' not found in /var/www/example/public/modules/contrib/devel/devel_generate/src/Plugin/DevelGenerate/ContentDevelGenerate.php on line 391 #0 /var/www/example/public/modules/contrib/devel/devel_generate/src/Form/DevelGenerateForm.php(95): Drupal\devel_generate\Plugin\DevelGenerate\ContentDevelGenerate->settingsFormValidate()\n#1 [internal function]: Drupal\devel_generate\Form\DevelGenerateForm->validateForm()\n#2 /var/www/example/public/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormValidator.php(82): call_user_func_array()\n#3 /var/www/example/public/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormValidator.php(275): Drupal\Core\Form\FormValidator->executeValidateHandlers()\n#4 /var/www/example/public/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormValidator.php(118): Drupal\Core\Form\FormValidator->doValidateForm()\n#5 /var/www/example/public/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormBuilder.php(588): Drupal\Core\Form\FormValidator->validateForm()\n#6 /var/www/example/public/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormBuilder.php(...', referer: http://example.com/admin/config/development/generate/content

I'm not at all sure, but it looks like there is some prerequisite expected by Devel which I do not have. I'd appreciate anyone telling me the best way to fix this fatal error.

Comment: Is "drush" (latest version is recommended) installed? Does not hurt to try.

Comment: @BaldeBinos It does appear to be drush that is missing, but I'm not sure I agree that simply installing unfamiliar extensions/modules is ever a good approach.

Comment: @SImp Do you really consider “drush” in the category of “unfamiliar extensions/modules”?

Comment: @BaldeBinos it is not a core extension, does not appear among the extensions when you install it, and I have never dealt with it before in my life. So yes, I do consider it unfamiliar. Furthermore, it has nearly a score of dependencies when you install it. This leaves a lot of surface area for problems to affect your drupal install. Any one of those dependencies might have a bug, might be deprecated, might be compromised by malware, might stop working in a new version of PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @BaldeBinos in comments, I installed drush using composer as [described here](https://www.drush.org/latest/install/). This involved connecting via CLI, switching my working directory to where I have drupal installed, and running a composer command:

```bash
cd /var/www/mydrupal
composer require drush/drush
```

This and downloads and installs various perhaps 20 archives, the last of which is drush/drush:

```
Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
Using version ^11.3 for drush/drush
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update drush/drush
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Lock file operations: 22 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Locking chi-teck/drupal-code-generator (2.6.1)
  - Locking consolidation/annotated-command (4.6.0)
  - Locking consolidation/config (2.1.2)
  - Locking consolidation/filter-via-dot-access-data (2.0.2)
  - Locking consolidation/log (2.1.1)
  - Locking consolidation/output-formatters (4.2.3)
  - Locking consolidation/robo (3.0.10)
  - Locking consolidation/self-update (2.0.5)
  - Locking consolidation/site-alias (4.0.0)
  - Locking consolidation/site-process (4.2.1)
  - Locking dflydev/dot-access-data (v3.0.2)
  - Locking drush/drush (11.3.2)
  - Locking enlightn/security-checker (v1.10.0)
  - Locking grasmash/expander (2.0.3)
  - Locking league/container (4.2.0)
  - Locking nikic/php-parser (v4.15.1)
  - Locking psy/psysh (v0.11.8)
  - Locking symfony/filesystem (v5.4.13)
  - Locking symfony/finder (v5.4.11)
  - Locking symfony/polyfill-intl-grapheme (v1.26.0)
  - Locking symfony/string (v5.4.15)
  - Locking webflo/drupal-finder (1.2.2)
Writing lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Package operations: 22 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Downloading consolidation/log (2.1.1)
  - Downloading symfony/finder (v5.4.11)
  - Downloading dflydev/dot-access-data (v3.0.2)
  - Downloading consolidation/output-formatters (4.2.3)
  - Downloading symfony/filesystem (v5.4.13)
  - Downloading consolidation/self-update (2.0.5)
  - Downloading webflo/drupal-finder (1.2.2)
  - Downloading nikic/php-parser (v4.15.1)
  - Downloading psy/psysh (v0.11.8)
  - Downloading league/container (4.2.0)
  - Downloading enlightn/security-checker (v1.10.0)
  - Downloading grasmash/expander (2.0.3)
  - Downloading consolidation/config (2.1.2)
  - Downloading consolidation/site-alias (4.0.0)
  - Downloading consolidation/site-process (4.2.1)
  - Downloading consolidation/annotated-command (4.6.0)
  - Downloading consolidation/robo (3.0.10)
  - Downloading consolidation/filter-via-dot-access-data (2.0.2)
  - Downloading symfony/polyfill-intl-grapheme (v1.26.0)
  - Downloading symfony/string (v5.4.15)
  - Downloading chi-teck/drupal-code-generator (2.6.1)
  - Downloading drush/drush (11.3.2)
  - Installing consolidation/log (2.1.1): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/finder (v5.4.11): Extracting archive
  - Installing dflydev/dot-access-data (v3.0.2): Extracting archive
  - Installing consolidation/output-formatters (4.2.3): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/filesystem (v5.4.13): Extracting archive
  - Installing consolidation/self-update (2.0.5): Extracting archive
  - Installing webflo/drupal-finder (1.2.2): Extracting archive
  - Installing nikic/php-parser (v4.15.1): Extracting archive
  - Installing psy/psysh (v0.11.8): Extracting archive
  - Installing league/container (4.2.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing enlightn/security-checker (v1.10.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing grasmash/expander (2.0.3): Extracting archive
  - Installing consolidation/config (2.1.2): Extracting archive
  - Installing consolidation/site-alias (4.0.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing consolidation/site-process (4.2.1): Extracting archive
  - Installing consolidation/annotated-command (4.6.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing consolidation/robo (3.0.10): Extracting archive
  - Installing consolidation/filter-via-dot-access-data (2.0.2): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-intl-grapheme (v1.26.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/string (v5.4.15): Extracting archive
  - Installing chi-teck/drupal-code-generator (2.6.1): Extracting archive
  - Installing drush/drush (11.3.2): Extracting archive
    Cleaning: symfony/finder
    Cleaning: symfony/filesystem
4 package suggestions were added by new dependencies, use `composer suggest` to see details.
Package doctrine/reflection is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use roave/better-reflection instead.
Package symfony/debug is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use symfony/error-handler instead.
Generating autoload files
Hardening vendor directory with .htaccess and web.config files.
53 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!
Cleaning installed packages.
No security vulnerability advisories found
```

It seems to be all that is required but NOTE that **drush does not appear among my installed modules at /admin/modules**. After this one composer command, I was able to repeat the steps in my original post and the temporary/test content was generated successfully.